# Please help me identify the bold slashes between staves

Tags: notation

Bold slashes are between every staff.  I thought it may be pauses but it cannot be, wouldn't work.
Maybe they are decoration, I don't know.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

They are called "system dividers" or "system separators" and their purpose is to make it easier for the performers to find the next line of music, when the vertical spacing of the score is as tightly packed as your example.

They are more common in scores with more staves, or a variable number of staves, on each system. Four staves is about the minimum number where they make any difference to the readability.

Comment: Or vocal scores, even with less than four staves, especially if you have choir + soli + piano reduction and some of them are elided for a system or more. We really appreciate them.